# Unable to use rsocket-tcp-client package

Tags: rsocket

I would like to enable client my to reconnect to my server in case the server restarts. I am trying thus the following [piece of code](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/blob/c539b3a42d56780011392fc06ebd488d09f929da/packages/rsocket-examples/src/ResumeExample.js). The thing is, after adding this line `"rsocket-tcp-client": "^0.0.23"` to my `package.json`  and after running `$npm install && ng update && ng serve` I got the following error message :

```
Error: ./node_modules/rsocket-tcp-client/build/RSocketTcpClient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/gitter/myproject/node_modules/rsocket-tcp-client/build'

Error: ./node_modules/rsocket-tcp-client/build/RSocketTcpClient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/Users/gitter/myproject/node_modules/rsocket-tcp-client/build'
```

Any help please will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install *tls* and *net* packages as well if you are going to use that sample code.